# Django migrate naive DateTimeField

Tags: django

I am very sad: Every time I **migrate** the database, Django calls me naive:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Book.released received a naive datetime (2023-02-17 22:59:29.126480) while time zone support is active.
```

...and the worst part is: It's **impossible** to fix it!

Steps to reproduce:

```
$ python -V
Python 3.10.6
$ pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2022.11.11
$ mkdir naive-django
$ cd naive-django
$ pipenv install django
$ pipenv shell
$ python -m django --version
4.1.7
$ django-admin startproject naive_project
$ cd naive_project
$ python manage.py startapp naive_app
$ vim naive_project/settings.py
```

```py
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'naive_app.apps.NaiveAppConfig',
...
```

```
$ vim naive_app/models.py
```

```py
from django.db import models


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
```

No problem so far. Let's add a `DateTimeField` now:

```
$ vim naive_app/models.py
```

```py
from datetime import datetime
from django.db import models


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    released = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Book.released received a naive datetime (2023-02-17 22:59:29.126480) while time zone support is active.
```

Oh no! I made a **terrible mistake**! If only it was not impossible to fix it... Let's try anyway:

```
$ vim naive_app/models.py
```

```py
from django.utils import timezone  # timezone instead of datetime
from django.db import models


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    released = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)  # timezone instead of datetime
```

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
```

Hey! It worked! It was not impossible after all!

Let's write a test:

```
$ vim naive_app/tests.py
```

```py
from django.test import TestCase


class NaiveTests(TestCase):
    def test_naive(self):
        pass
```

```
$ python manage.py test
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Book.released received a naive datetime (2023-02-17 23:10:54.367162) while time zone support is active.
```

Oh no! It's not fixed! Every time I run the tests, a database is built from scratch and my **old migration** is executed!

```
$ echo "Please Mister Django, I apologize. I'm going to delete my model."
$ vim naive_app/models.py
```

```py
# from django.utils import timezone  # timezone instead of datetime
# from django.db import models
# 
# 
# class Book(models.Model):
#     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
#     released = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)  # timezone instead of datetime
```

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
$ python manage.py test
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Book.released received a naive datetime (2023-02-17 23:18:36.955394) while time zone support is active.
```

I still get a warning while the model is **deleted** and the test is almost **empty**.

Would you have an idea?

```
$ exit
$ pipenv --rm
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf naive-django
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [squash](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations) the two migrations that add the `DateTimeField` and fix the default they will be optimised into a single migration that uses the latest default, the old operation using the incorrect default will then not run so you shouldn't get the warning

```
$ python manage.py squashmigrations naive_app 0002 0003
$ python manage.py migrate
$ python manage.py test
```